# Nancy C# simulate WS

Tags: web-services, simulate, nancy

I'm trying to use the Framework to Nancy C # to an MVC application running on internal control target (eg, read the serial port and send a response), without having to have IIS installed or having to install a complete structure of WS ...

But how do I simulate the WS utilziando Nancy ...
example:
`Send http://localhost:1234/comandos` and understand it and return True or False ...

Another thing, how to use user authentication in this situation?
There are alternatives to my problem?

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you start by reading through the [Nancy documentation](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/Documentation).

You are probably going to need to run a [self hosted Nancy application](http://theburningmonk.com/2011/09/nancy-self-hosting/).

And you can read about [authentication in the docs.](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/Documentation)